# Pretty Print Minified CSS Files in Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Simply unable to pretty print minified CSS files in the style editor in developer tools in Firefox Developer Edition. I know in past Firefox versions there was a button at the bottom of Developer Tools (the {}). Has anybody else figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I re-installed Firefox and now I see the pretty print option again.

EDIT: This fixed the pretty print for the *Debugger* tab, not the *Style Editor* tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're saying that you are seeing a pretty print option in Firefox Developer Edition, in the Shade Editor? I had already re-installed for other reasons, but nothing changed.

Comment: I am also unable to find a Pretty Print option for the Style Editor in either standard Firefox or Developer Edition. I can't even find anything in their documentation to suggest it ever existed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you were specifically talking about the _Style Editor_ tab. I don't see a pretty print button in that particular tab. To my understanding, this is how it should look. If you look at the screenshots and videos in the documentation, there is not pretty print button in the _Style Editor_:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor

Answer (score 0):

Chrome devtools has it, not Firefox.

Comment: @pjones235 can you elaborate on that? The question appears to be how to do find the functionality in Firefox that does that. The answer is that Firefox doesn't have that functionality. OP might remember the feature from Chrome and thought it was Firefox.